# Gatling during explanation

Tags: scala, gatling

I´m using Gatling, and I want to repeat a command for an hour so I see there´s one operator `during`.

The documentation it´s not clear enough

```
during

.during(duration, counterName, exitASAP) {
  myChain
}
duration can be an Int for a duration in seconds, or a duration expressed like 500 milliseconds.
```

My question is, during will execute the task in 1 hour duration, or it will repeat the task for an hour.

I know we have `repeat` operator as well, but that it will require me to know how much time it takes my task to finish and then calc the number of repeats.

Comment: You are right paul. There is very less documentation. ??Hardly i could find this link. Happy if it helps you https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/OxRJbMXh23E

Comment: Thanks for the link. Seems during does not work as I expect

Comment: I used gattling for one project. The code in the during block will run for the duration of seconds you give. 
When the scenario is executed then the iterations in the during block are run until the duration.

Answer (score 3):

The code in the during block will run for the duration of seconds you give.

When the scenario is executed then the iterations in the **during** block are run until the duration.

Using **.during()** with amount of seconds. you can constantly increase the users, ramp, split the users but cannot repeat the task